# why setting framework "install Directory" to "@executable_path/../Frameworks"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

while creating cocoa framework on Xcode 5.1.1,

it is suggested to add

"install Directory" to "@executable_path/../Frameworks"

which is present at Xcode path: "Build Setting->Deployment->install Directory".

My question is why we are setting "install Directory" to "@executable_path/../Frameworks".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple tell it best [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/OverviewOfDynamicLibraries.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001873-SW1), but the key phrase is:

> The static linker records the filenames of each of the dependent
>   libraries at the time the app is linked. This filename is known as the
>   dynamic library’s **install name**.

So in other words setting the *install name* tells the dynamic linker where to find the dependent library at runtime.

(The *static linker* being `ld`, which is used during development to link the executable and the *dynamic linker* being `/usr/lib/dyld`, which is used at runtime to load the dependent libraries).

However, I prefer to set the install name to `@rpath/nameOfLibrary.dylib` and then set the *Run Path* of the executable to `@executable_path/../Frameworks`.  This creates a [Run-Path Dependent Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/RunpathDependentLibraries.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008306-SW1) which I have found to be more convenient in most cases.